# Getting VBA to display a formula with Subtracting

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a question yesterday on how to use VBA to display formulas within cells, which I now can use, except for my attempt at a subtraction.

I have my code here, is anyone able to point me in the right direction to get this to work.

```
With Worksheets(c10)
.Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 3, 2).Formula = "=Sum((" & .Range(.Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 6, 2)).Address(0, 0) & ") - (" & .Range(.Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 2, 2)).Address(0, 0) & "))" 
End With
```

I belived this to be the most likly method after a few different attempt to make it work.

To produce something like in `Cells(NewEngineRowNumber+3,2)` in the formula bar to display `=Cells(BX) - Cells(BY)`, where X = NewEngineRowNumber +6 and Y = NewEngineRowNumber +2

Any help in helping me  understand how to edit this to make it work would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what the formula is supposed to look like for a certain NewEngineRowNumber value?

Comment: just added a edit Greg, does that help you

Comment: You should remove the .Address(0, 0) from your formula...

Comment: That's better, but the formula you show is not a valid formula. If I put =Cells(BX) in the formula bar I'm going to get a NAME error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try doing all in one code line. Do separating it in multiple code lines is better for debugging:

```
With Worksheets(c10)
 sAddress1 = .Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 6, 2).Address(0, 0)
 sAddress2 = .Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 2, 2).Address(0, 0)
 sFormula = "=Sum(" & sAddress1 & "-" & sAddress2 & ")"

 .Cells(NewEngineRowNumber + 3, 2).Formula = sFormula
End With
```

But why are you thinking the `SUM` is necessary at all?

```
 sFormula = "=" & sAddress1 & "-" & sAddress2
```

should also work.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was an attempt at editing a previous method that worked which sum a column. I sued Sum as that what I would have written in the cell Manually. Thank you ever so much :) #